# Is it possible in redux (react) to set initialState to null and then update inside reducer to object?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a simple store:

```js
import { userReducer } from './UserSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
});
```

My goal is to have inital value of user object set to `null` and after i update that user it should be an `User` object:

```js
export type User = {
  id?: string;
  username?: string;
  role?: string;
};
```

So i tried to create a slice with initial state of `null` but i have an issue that typescript complains that if i want to update from `null -> User` that state might be `null` which is true.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/react';  
import { User } from '../types/User'; 
 
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: null as User | null,
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action: { payload: User; type: string }) => {
      state = action.payload;
    },
    setRole: (state, action: { payload: string; type: string }) => {
      state.role = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setUser, setRole } = userSlice.actions;
export const userReducer = userSlice.reducer;
```

But even if try to check if state is null i dont know how to utilize it with immer style. Also there are issues with setting single property of that object.

So my question is how to do with `null -> Object` with immer style?

Or is my approach wrong altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using a guard on the potentially null/undefined object references. Only access `state.role` to mutate it if `state` exists.

Example:

```js
setRole: (state, action: { payload: string; type: string }) => {
  if (state) {
    state.role = action.payload;
  }
},
```

There's also an issue with your `setUser` reducer. In Redux-Toolkit you can write mutable state updates ***or*** you can return a new state reference, but never both, and you shouldn't ever ***reassign*** the `state`. If you want to set the `user` state to the payload then simply ***return*** the payload as the next state value.

```js
import type { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
...

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: null as User | null,
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<User>) => {
      return action.payload; // <-- return new user object
    },
    setRole: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      if (state) { // <-- check that state exists
        state.role = action.payload;
      }
    },
  },
});
```

I find it's often just easer to maintain a state invariant that always exists and make the properties optional/nullable. You still need null-checks on these properties.

Example:

```js
type UserState = {
  user: User | null; // <-- nullable property
}

const initialState: UserState = {
  user: null
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<User>) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    setRole: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      if (state.user) {
        state.user.role = action.payload;
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Create and export a selector function so you don't need to write `state.user.user` in the UI.

```js
export const userSelector = (state: RootState) => state.user.user;
```

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { userSelector } from '../path/to/userSlice';

...

const user = useSelector(userSelector);
```

Comment: Yes the first part works! Thanks a lot. For second part i knew it would work but i wanted to avoid `state.user.user` (double user object) as it looks cleaner. That is why i asked the question. Anyway thanks again!